# Updating PATH variable on Linux

Tags: c, linux, file, exec, system

I´m trying to update the PATH variable through a program in c but when i try to update it, it comes the problems. I have tried system("source .profile") and execlp("source", "source", ".profile", NULL) but none of them works, I do not know how to make it run so the PATH get update. Has anybody an idea about this? Thanks.

Comment: Environment variables are specific to a process, and are inherited by child processes.  If you start another process to change an environment variable, the environment variable may be changed in the other process, but the variable in the original process will be completely unaffected.

Comment: I haven´t create a new process to do it, just modifying .profile file. I just want to uptade it to set permanently that PATH

Comment: *I haven´t create a new process to do it*  You actually do.  That's what `system("source .profile")` does - it starts a child process.

Comment: Oh yeah I see the point, but why using execlp it also don't update the environment variable?

Comment: I want to set permanently a new path with this script but this is the problem tu update the original one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [setenv](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) function in stdlib.h to set environment variables

> The setenv() function adds the variable name to the environment with
> the value value, if name does not already exist.  If name does exist
> in the environment, then its value is changed to value if overwrite is
> nonzero; if overwrite is zero, then the value of name is not changed
> (and setenv() returns a success status). This function makes copies of
> the strings pointed to by name and value (by contrast with putenv(3)).
>
> The unsetenv() function deletes the variable name from the
> environment.  If name does not exist in the environment, then the
> function succeeds, and the environment is unchanged.

Comment: I have already tried but this is just temporaly, i want to set permanently so i have to modify .profile.